# How to play synchronised multichannel Audio and Video in a C# WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg, video-processing, naudio

I have video of approximate length 2 mins, and i need to be able to switch between audio streams accompanying the video during playback and even apply varying digital filtering and gain changes to the active audio stream during playback.

NAudio can cope with the mutlichannel audio, filtering and switching between streams, but there is no support for synchronization with a video.

How do programmers achieve synchronization, without embedding the audio into the video container directly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use GStreamer ?

Comment: It has C# bindings (https://www.nuget.org/packages/GstSharp/), samples (https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer-sharp) and more samples (https://github.com/ttustonic/GStreamerSharpSamples). The last one is mine, and there are some simple WPF and Winforms demos.